# calling a template method results in no match for 'operator<'

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem with the following Minimal Example:

```
enum class modes_t {m1=0u, m2=1u};

class A {
    public:
    static inline A& get(void) noexcept{
        static A inst;
        return inst;
    }
    template<modes_t mode>
    inline void start(void) noexcept {}
};

template<typename T>
class B {
    public:
    static inline void start(void) noexcept {
        T::get().start<modes_t::m1>();
    }
};

int main() {
    B<A>::start();
}
```

If I compile it with g++ v.7.3, (with -std=c++17 and also with -std=c++14) I get the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In static member function ‘static void B<T>::start()’:
main.cpp:17:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
         T::get().start<modes_t::m1>();
                                     ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static void B<T>::start() [with T = A]’:
main.cpp:22:11:   required from here
main.cpp:17:23: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘modes_t’)
         T::get().start<modes_t::m1>();
```

So the compiler thinks, that the line `T::get().start<modes_t::m1>();` is a less then comparison of `T::get().start` and `modes_t::m1`. 
What should I do, to tell the compiler, that this expression should call `start()` in class `A`?

Comment: Remember that [scoped enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) are strongly typed. They can't be implicitly cast to `int`.

Comment: sorry, this was a bug from me, it is clear, that this can't be int. I fixed it already in the original post.

Comment: Also remember that enumeratoins can "inherit" base type, for example `unsigned`, which will make all values unsigned (so you don't need the explicit `=0u` for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `template` keyword to tell the compiler that `start` is a member function **template**. e.g.

```
T::get().template start<modes_t::m1>();
//       ~~~~~~~~
```

BTW: You can't specify `modes_t::m1` as the template argument; `start` expects an `int` as its template parameter and there are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped enumerator to integral types.